# PHP - Invalid argument supplied for foreach() warning message

Tags: php, serialization, foreach

```
$data = file_get_contents($file);

$fexplode = explode(PHP_EOL, $data);

foreach ($fexplode as $uline) {
     foreach (unserialize($uline) as $item => $value){ 
         echo $item . " :  ";
         echo $value;
     }
}
```

Getting a "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() " warning on my page when running this code

Comment: have you tried to print_r($fexplode) ? is it printing an array ?

Comment: @VikrantVirBhalla when I use print_r($fexplode); it gives me this Array ( [0] => a:3:{s:8:"Player 1";s:7:"Scissor";s:8:"Player 2";s:6:"Lizard";s:7:"Results";s:36:"Scissor beats Lizard. Player 1 wins!";} [1] => a:3:{s:8:"Player 1";s:6:"Lizard";s:8:"Player 2";s:5:"Spock";s:7:"Results";s:34:"Lizard beats Spock. Player 1 wins!";} [2] => a:3:{s:8:"Player 1";s:4:"Rock";s:8:"Player 2";s:4:"Rock";s:7:"Results";s:5:"Draw!";}

It appears the unserialize is not unserializing all the data but only parts?

Comment: @VikrantVirBhalla if I print_r after unserialization it gives me this 


a:3:{s:8:"Player 1";s:6:"Lizard";s:8:"Player 2";s:5:"Spock";s:7:"Results";s:34:"Lizard beats Spock. Player 1 wins!";}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below way

```
$data = file_get_contents($file);

$fexplode = (!empty($data)?explode(PHP_EOL, $data):array()); // use !empty otherwise make empty array

foreach ($fexplode as $uline) {
     foreach (unserialize($uline) as $item => $value){ 
         echo $item . " :  ";
         echo $value;
     }
}
```

Comment: This still gives me the invalid argument warning

Comment: what is the content of  $data, please use var_dump($data);  and share

Comment: a:3:{s:8:"Player 1";s:7:"Scissor";s:8:"Player 2";s:6:"Lizard";s:7:"Results";s:36:"Scissor beats Lizard. Player 1 wins!";}
a:3:{s:8:"Player 1";s:6:"Lizard";s:8:"Player 2";s:5:"Spock";s:7:"Results";s:34:"Lizard beats Spock. Player 1 wins!";}
a:3:{s:8:"Player 1";s:4:"Rock";s:8:"Player 2";s:4:"Rock";s:7:"Results";s:5:"Draw!";}
a:3:{s:8:"Player 1";s:7:"Scissor";s:8:"Player 2";s:6:"Lizard";s:7:"Results";s:36:"Scissor beats Lizard. Player 1 wins!";}

Comment: This is copied straight out of the file and not from var dump but after var_dump it's essentially the same thing just with an added "string(648)" in front of it.

Comment: Yhea it's seems like that, u tried using unserialize

Comment: use this way to serialze                                                                                //to safely serialize
$safe_string_to_store = base64_encode(serialize($multidimensional_array));

//to unserialize...
$array_restored_from_db = unserialize(base64_decode($encoded_serialized_string));